# STM32F446RE PLL Config: What are the benefits and drawbacks of using different PLLCFGR register settings to achieve the same PLL output frequency?

Tags: stm32, embedded

**Background**

I am learning how to configure the System Clock, and I am seeking help in understanding the benefits and drawbacks of various combinations of settings for PLLM, PLLN, and PLLP in the PLLCFGR register.

For example, if I wish to set the System Clock to 84 MHz using the internal 16MHz clock source (HSI RC), I can do so in several ways. A list of some possible configurations follows:

A. Set PLLM to to 1/16, set PLLN to 336, and PLLP to 1/4.
f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> = 16MHz * (1/16) = 1MHz
f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> = f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> * (336) = 336MHz
f<sub>PLL_OUT</sub> = f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> * (1/4) = 84MHz

B. Set PLLM to to 1/16, set PLLN to 168, and PLLP to 1/2.
f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> = 16MHz * (1/16) = 1MHz
f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> = f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> * (168) = 168MHz
f<sub>PLL_OUT</sub> = f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> * (1/2) = 84MHz

C. Set PLLM to to 1/8, set PLLN to 168, and PLLP to 1/4.
f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> = 16MHz *(1/8) = 2MHz
f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> = f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> * (168) = 336MHz
f<sub>PLL_OUT</sub> = f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> * (1/4) = 84MHz

D. Set PLLM to to 1/8, set PLLN to 84, and PLLP to 1/2.
f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> = 16MHz *(1/8) = 2MHz
f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> = f<sub>PLL_IN</sub> * (84) = 168MHz
f<sub>PLL_OUT</sub> = f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub> * (1/2) = 84MHz

**What I have found in the documentation**

Section 6.3.11, PLL characteristics, of the datasheet (DS10693 Rev 10) indicates max, min, and typical values for these three (and other) frequencies relating to the PLL in Table 43, Main PLL Characteristics. The three frequencies I have mentioned are shown:

f<sub>PLL_IN</sub>: 0.95MHz min, 1MHz typ, and 2.1MHz max
f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub>: 100MHz min, N/A typ, and 432MHz max
f<sub>PLL_OUT</sub>: 12.5MHz min, N/A typ, and 180MHz max

The table also indicates min and max values for the PLL lock time:
@f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub>=100MHz: 75us min, 200ms max
@f<sub>VCO_OUT</sub>=432MHz: 100us min, 300ms max

Section 6.3.2, RCC PLL configuration register (RCC_PLLCFGR), of the reference manual (RM0390 Rev 6) includes a cautionary note about the PLLM bits (bits[5:0]):

"The software has to set these bits correctly to ensure that the VCO input frequency
ranges from 1 to 2 MHz. It is recommended to select a frequency of 2 MHz to limit
PLL jitter".

**My question(s)**

1. Am I correct in identifying Configuration D as the optimal choice in this case? Choosing f<sub>PLL_IN</sub>=2MHz minimizes jitter, and choosing a lower value of f<sub>VCO_out</sub> reduces the PLL lock time.
2. In general, what might be some benefits and drawbacks of these configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have researched so far looks true, and on many different STM32 MCUs.

1. With highest possible reference input to PLL, the jitter is smallest. Lowest VCO output frequency not only reduces lock time, but will also consume least current running the VCO analog and digital circuitry.
2. Only based on what you already knew from documents:

A will have large jitter and high power consumption.
B will have large jitter but low power consumption.
It is not known whether A or B has higher or lower jitter.
C will have low jitter and high power consumption.
D will have low jitter, low power consumption, and faster lock time than C.

At least the power consumption is related to frequency but regarding lock time it is not known, and most likely irrelevant.

I think any combination within specs will be good enough. Usually jitter is not an issue, unless you know your application will be sensitive to MCU clock jitter - for example it may not be possible to clock an Ethernet PHY with a clock made with STM32 PLL.

One note though, since you are using the internal 16 MHz HSI oscillator. As it is factory calibrated to 1% accuracy, and over -10/+85 temperature range it is only 4% accurate, and over full -40/+105 range it can be only  -8%/+4.5% accurate, you must also make sure that under all conditions the frequencies fed into PLL, VCO output, or PLL output, are not out of specs.